# Nginx redirect/rewrite vBulletin URLs (with slug) to XenForo

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, redirect, ngx-http-rewrite-module

Nginx redirect/rewrite Rule

How to make the configuration of nginx for redirection:

Old Url

http://www.webcheats.com.br/forum/elsword-downloads-de-cheats-utilitarios/2369461-26-04-revolution-trainer-elsword.html

1. /forum/ - It is the folder that installed vbulletin
2. /elsword-downloads-de-cheats-utilitarios/ - is the forum name that the topic / in xenforo will not appear
3. 2369461 - is the ID that will have to appear in the url xenforo
4. -26-04-revolution-trainer-elsword.html - is the topic name that accessing, no matter what the xenforo because with the right ID it corrects the topic name in the URL.

New Url

http://www.webcheats.com.br/threads/26-04-revolution-trainer-elsword.2369461/

1. /threads/ - the xenforo automatically add the address when accessing this one topic.
2. 26-04-revolution-trainer-elsword - Topic name, even if the xenforo system corrects'm wrong
3. 2369461 - Most importantly, the topic ID

Another examples

Old Url
www.webcheats.com.br/forum/resolvidos/2343690-reposicao-dos-meus-posts.html

New Url
www.webcheats.com.br/threads/reposição-dos-meus-posts.2343690/

Old Url
www.webcheats.com.br/forum/league-of-legends-downloads-de-cheats-utilitarios/2516190-drophack-1-3-funcional-apenas-por-30-dias-aproveite-o-mais-rapido-possivel-veja-ma.html

New Url
www.webcheats.com.br/threads/drophack-1-3-funcional-apenas-por-30-dias-aproveite-o-mais-rapido-possivel-veja-ma.2516190/

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How to make the configuration of nginx for redirection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to you server `www.webcheats.com.br` config

```
location ^~ /forum/ {
    rewrite ^/forum/(.+)/([0-9]+)-(.+)\.html$ /threads/$3.$2/ redirect;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to not carry over the [*slug*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL#Slug), as it may or may not be the same, so, might as well discard it right away, and make XenForo makes its own one.

```
location ^~ /forum/ {
    rewrite ^/forum/[^/]+/([0-9]+)- /threads/$1 redirect;
}
```